# Pycharm - Attempt of Package download results in http 404 code

Tags: windows, installation, pycharm

I am trying to resolve this for days now and haven't found a solution. I looked at the official help center and also around the web.

The message I get when I try to refresh: "Error updating package list: Connection failed with HTTP code 404"

I use PyCharm 2016.2.3 on a Windows 10 machine.

Answer (score 0):

Click the Manage Repositories add https://pypi.python.org/simple to the list.